# Unable to understand the logic in enqueue function

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I came through a code to insert element in a queue but I am unable to understand how the show function is working

```
void enqueue(int x)
{
  queue *ptr;
  queue *ptr1;
  ptr=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
  ptr->info=x;
  if(front==rear&&front==NULL)
  {
      ptr->next=NULL;
      front=rear=ptr;
  }
  else
    {
   while(rear->next!=NULL)
   {
       rear=rear->next;
   }
   rear->next=ptr;
   ptr->next=NULL;
  }
}
```

//As there is no link between front and rear I am unable to understand how next to front is pointing to next element in the queue

```
 void show()
 {
  queue *ptr=front;
  while(ptr!=NULL)
   {
    printf("%d\n",ptr->info);
    ptr=ptr->next;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no link between front and rear

Of course there is - here is how it is established:

```
if(front==rear&&front==NULL)
{
    ptr->next=NULL;
    front=rear=ptr;
}
```

`front` points to the first inserted element. Initially, `rear` points to the same element as well. As you add more elements to the queue, `rear` moves on, while `front` remains pointing to the same initial element.

`show()` takes that element, and traverses the linked list using it.

Note that if items are always inserted using `insert`, the `while` loop is unnecessary, because `rear->next!=NULL` is always "false".

Comment: But where I have specified that front->next will point to rear

Comment: @Newbie786 At the beginning of the second call to `insert()`, `front` and `rear` point to the same element. When you insert an element at `rear->next`, `front->next` also points to the same element, because `front==rear`.

Comment: Okay now I am getting it

Answer (score 0):

This is your code, and I am making comments what your code is doing.

```
void enqueue(int x)
{
  queue *ptr;
  queue *ptr1;
  ptr=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));  // allocating memory
  ptr->info=x;  // x is the value you are passing to ptr.
  if(front==rear&&front==NULL) //this work for the first time when list is empty
  {
      ptr->next=NULL;    //setting next location to null
      front=rear=ptr;    //till now only once value is there in the list so front=rear (both will be same) = ptr
  }
  else
  {
       while(rear->next!=NULL)  // while loop will run until end of the list reached
       {
           rear=rear->next;     // moving to next location
       }

   rear->next=ptr;     // after getting last location assign it to rear->next
   ptr->next=NULL;   // again make next loation null.
  }
}
```

Comment: but how the show function is working as there is no link between front and rear